# Prevent errors, warnings from being logged to event viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, enterprise-library

I would like to stop writing logs (error, warning) to event viewer. I am already using  EnterpriseLibrary.Logging to Rolling Flat file.

But want to stop to write to event log. Is there any configuration that I can use in web.config

Comment: Why does this matter?

Comment: There are lot of warning writing on event log. I want turn off for some time until it resolved